# Get pid of started process c++

Tags: c++, windows

I try to get PID of process which i started by my app.

```
 DWORD dwPid = GetProcessId(pi.hProcess);
```

Somewhere on this forum is this solution but i dont have func "GetProcessId"

To start process i'm using:

```
BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
LPTSTR pszCmd = NULL;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;// = {0};
STARTUPINFO si = {0};
si.cb = sizeof(si);

pszCmd = ""; /* assign something useful */
bSuccess = CreateProcess("D:\\program\\program.exe",NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, "D:\\program", &si, &pi);
if (bSuccess)
{

}
```

1. It is possible to run my code in this started program without dll ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation on `PROCESS_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can access the process id directly from the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` struct by accessing the `dwProcessId` member:

```
DWORD dwPid = pi.dwProcessId;
```

Comment: Ohh thanks ;p  
Could you tell me what is called the way to get all arg function in other program ?

The same in ollydbg , i make breakpoint get functions arg

Comment: I don't know the answers to these additional questions - why not submit them as separate questions on StackOverflow? Also, if this issue is resolved, please make sure to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).